# Не работает функция получения значения из input

Tags: javascript, html, input, функции

Доброго дня, кто может помогите, в программе приходиться получать очень много элементов input, хотел оптимизировать это действие таким вот образом:

```
function get (id){
    var x = document.getElementById(id);

    return parseFloat(x.value);
}
```

Функцию использую по простому: `get(something)`, просто вставляя `id` из нужного `input`, никак не декларируя его, после этого всё перестало работать, ну и плюс пишет `Unresolved variable or type`. Получается нельзя так делать, или я просто накосячил где?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отличный сайт, как напишу сюда вопрос сразу становиться понятно что не так, видно стыд перед собратьями разгоняет мозг. В общем всё работает, надо только когда передаёшь id брать его в кавычки:

`get("something");`

Нда, сразу ещё один вопрос, может кто-нибудь написать как удалять отсюда вопросы, а то второй раз так попадаю, стыдно как-то )

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот вопрос может оказаться полезным кому-нибудь, потому можно и не удалять его.

Comment: И, кстати, рекомендую почитать ответы тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables, у вас была проблема именно из-за этого.

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо )